# Awk and sed command on the same time

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have 2 files, the English file (source file) and the Italian file (target file). Both of them have the **same number of lines**. I run `awk 'NF<3'` to remove all the strings in my Italian file having more than 2 words, but at the same time I'd like to remove the specific source strings erased from the Italian file in the English file (I thought I could work on the line number). Naturally, I have to perform a `sed` command on the line number of the source string (cause the strings in both file are different), but I do not know how to do that at the same time while I'm using `awk` to remove those strings from the Italian file, because when I launched the command, I lose the equivalent line numbers in the files.

Example

```
EN
1 Santa Claus
2 Pigs don't fly
3 The son of the father
4 Elf

IT
1 Babbo Natale
2 I maiali non volano
3 Il figlio del padre
4 Elfo

I run awk on IT file
OUTPUT FILE
IT
1 Babbo Natale
4 Elfo
```

the lines removed with `awk` in the IT file need to be also removed from the EN file (**i can't use again awk on the eng file, cause the word count on the eng file is different with the IT file**, it's only a line number work)

```
THE OUTPUT EN FILE MUST BE
1 Santa Claus
2 Elf
```

Any suggestions?
If it's not clear, please ask...

Comment: You cannot accomplish that with `sed` and `awk`...  you need to accomplish it with only `awk`.  @klashxx has a possible solution for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having as *source* files:

```
$ cat it.dat 
Babbo Natale
I maiali non volano
Il figlio del padre
Elfo

$ cat en.dat 
Santa Claus
Pigs don't fly
The son of the father
Elf
```

This `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if(NF>3){a[NR]}else{a[NR]=1;print > "filtered_it.dat"}}
     NR!=FNR && a[FNR]{print > "filtered_en.dat"}' it.dat en.dat
```

**Results**

```
$ cat filtered_id.dat 
Babbo Natale
Elfo
$ cat filtered_en.dat 
Santa Claus
Elf
```

Comment: Thank you for your help... Happy Holidays... :)

Comment: Sorry again, but if in this command i'd like to integrate something that removes duplicate strings from the it.txt file (and therefore removed even on the en.txt) with awk, how do i do? where do i add this `awk !a[$0]++;`?

Comment: That's a different problem @JohnnyKing94 i suggest you to post another question including both source files with dup examples

Comment: Done, i would be glad if you help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473490/remove-duplicates-from-2-filtered-files-with-awk

;)
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn 's/\S+//3;T;=' fileIT | sed 's/.*/&d/' | sed -f - fileEN
```

This uses the IT file to create a sed file that is run against the EN file. The first sed invocation ouputs a line number of any line in the IT file that has three or more words on a line. The second sed invocation turns the line number into a sed command to delete that line number. The third sed invocation deletes those line numbers from the EN file.