# Remove duplicates from 2 filtered files with awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have 2 source files (an english file and an italian file) with the **same number of lines** and i perform an `awk command` to remove all lines from the IT.txt file which have more than 2 words

```
EN.txt
Santa Claus
Pigs don't fly
The son of the father
Elf
Santa Claus
Elf
Sabatons
Shoes

IT.txt
Babbo Natale
I maiali non volano
Il figlio del padre
Elfo
Babbo Natale
Elfo
Scarpe
Scarpe
```

So basically i have this kind of output:

```
EN.txt
Santa Claus
Pigs don't fly
The son of the father
Elf
Santa Claus
Elf
Sabatons
Shoes

IT.txt
Babbo Natale
Elfo
Babbo Natale
Elfo
Scarpe
Scarpe
```

But at the same time, i'd like to remove the same related strings from the EN.txt file. I thought I could work on the line number (for a moment, then i found out a better solution) and not on running another awk command to remove in the same way the strings having more than 2 words in the EN file, **because a translation could be different from the source string** (like having more words). So i need to focus my work to the IT file and the EN file must suffer the effect of command i launched. Therefore, my filtered output must be like this:

```
EN.txt
Santa Claus
Elf
Santa Claus
Elf
Sabatons
Shoes

IT.txt
Babbo Natale
Elfo
Babbo Natale
Elfo
Scarpe
Scarpe
```

this is the command i tried with (suggested with a previous question) and it works perfectly: `awk 'NR==FNR{if(NF>3){a[NR]}else{a[NR]=1;print > "filtered_it.txt"}} NR!=FNR && a[FNR]{print > "filtered_en.txt"}' IT.txt EN.txt`

But now i'd like to add extra on this command, like removing duplicates in order to have an output like this, but being careful to those lines that may have the same translation in italian but their respective source strings are different (like ***Sabatons*** and **Shoes** translated into **Scarpe**). In conclusion, i need to remove the duplicates only from both files at the same time (somehow) and not from a single one running each single command.

```
EN.txt
Santa Claus
Elf
Sabatons
Shoes

IT.txt
Babbo Natale
Elfo
Scarpe
Scarpe
```

Comment: Are those leading numbers REALLY present in your input and output files? If yes then edit your question to state that, if not then edit your question to remove them.

Comment: Done... it was only for understanding ;)

Comment: Putting text that doesn't exist in your sample input/output files does not improve our understanding!

Comment: I don't see that there is a logic rule that can be applied to remove "Pigs don't fly", "Son of the father" etc. Do you think that is possible? Please edit your Q to indicate the "rules". Good luck.

Comment: That rule has been answered this morning if you read (i even included the command that does that), my question is to expand that command including the chance to remove duplicate entries for both files and how to do so

Comment: Its extremely unlikely that someones going to go looking at some other question to try to piece together your current requirements. Edit your current question to stand alone with 1 set of clear requirements and sample input/output if you really want people to help you.

Comment: Ok i fixed the question, check it out if it's ok now... ;) Happy holidays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spec is very confusing but I think this is what you wanted.  Also, instead of operating on two files, if they are supposed to be matched line by line it's easier to start doing that first.

```
$ paste EN.txt IT.txt
          | awk -F'\t' '{n=split($1,_," ");
                         m=split($2,_," ")} 
 n<3 && m<3 && !a[$0]++ {print $1 > "f_EN.txt";
                         print $2 > "f_IT.txt"}' 

$ cat f_EN.txt 
Santa Claus
Elf
Sabatons
Shoes

$ cat f_IT.txt   
Babbo Natale
Elfo
Scarpe
Scarpe
```

ps. You either believe time travel is possible or using "tomorrow" instead of "yesterday" :)

Comment: Just one thing, setting the word count for both EN.txt and IT.txt files, it's incorrect... cause i may have a different and long translation for italian compared to the english source string... so i changed the command to:

`paste en.txt it.txt | awk -F'\t' '{n=split($1,_," "); m=split($2,_," ")} m<3 && !a[$0]++ {print $1 > "f_EN.txt"; print $2 > "f_IT.txt"}'`

It's okay what i wrote?

Comment: If so, remove the corresponding `split(..);` as well.  Note that $1 is for English and $2 is for Italian based on the input order.

Comment: I'm testing it on my huge language files, but i do not know i have some little bugs... like sometimes it collects a string with more than 3 words (and it's not even a full string, like truncated to a \n), maybe i need to use a delimiter when i use the paste command to avoid these... i'll let you know, if you have some ideas, tell me

Anyway the command worsk with the example i wrote, but now i need to know if it works with my files...

Comment: Ok i resolved like this `paste -d'\r' en.txt it.txt | awk -F'\r' '{n=split($1,_," "); m=split($2,_," ")} m<3 && !a[$0]++ {print $1 > "f_EN.txt"; print $2 > "f_IT.txt"}'` You have better idea?